# Does the C# 6 nameof get optimized out during build?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

For instance, if you have something like

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeFieldName => nameof(SomeField);
    public int SomeField = 3;
}
```

Will the nameof() call get replaced with the string nameof() would return? In this case, "SomeField".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. `nameof` is a language feature, not a CLR feature. It compiles down to a string constant.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I figured so, but I just wanted to make sure. Will mark as answer once I can.